# TypeORM soft deleted link in junction table

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I quite new to TypeORM and trying to use a many-to-many relation with help of a junction table (or "link table").

I am using soft deletes in my database – even on relation links in the junction table.

When constructing a query with the queryBuilder, I would like exclude related entities if the link is soft deleted.

I can't find anything in the documentation or any question on Stackoverflow about this. So I am starting to wonder if it's possible or even a such a terrible idea that no one else has come to think about soft deleting links? :-D

**A simplified example of my tables looks like this:**

```
UsersTable
*--------*-------------------------------*
| Id     | Name                          |
*--------*-------------------------------*
| 1      | Bruce Lee                     |
| 2      | Brad Pitt                     |
*--------*-------------------------------*

GroupsTable
*--------*-------------------------------*
| Id     | Name                          |
*--------*-------------------------------*
| 1      | Actors                        |
| 2      | Aliens                        |
*--------*-------------------------------*

JunctionTable
*--------*---------*---------------------*
| UserId | GroupId | DeletedAt           |
*--------*---------*---------------------*
| 1      | 1       |                     |
| 2      | 1       |                     |
| 2      | 2       | 2023-12-08 01:02:03 | <-- Brad Pitt is soft deleted
*--------*---------*---------------------*     from Aliens
```

**My entities looks like this:**

```js
@Entity('JuctionTable')
export class Jucation {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  UserId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  GroupId: number;

  @DeleteDateColumn() // Soft deleting column
  DeletedAt: Date;
}

@Entity('UsersTable')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  Id: number;

  @Column()
  Name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => GroupEntity, (group) => group.Users)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'JuctionTable',
    joinColumn: { referencedColumnName: 'Id', name: 'UserId' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { referencedColumnName: 'Id', name: 'GroupId' },
  })
  Groups: GroupEntity[];
}

@Entity('GroupsTable')
export class GroupEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  Id: number;

  @Column()
  Name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.Groups)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'JuctionTable',
    joinColumn: { referencedColumnName: 'Id', name: 'GroupId' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { referencedColumnName: 'Id', name: 'UserId' },
  })
  Users: UserEntity[];
}
```

**My query looks like this:**

```sql
const users = await myRepository.createQueryBuilder('User')
.innerJoinAndSelect('User.Groups', 'Groups')
.getMany();
```

**The data return looks like this:**

```
[
  {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Bruce Lee',
    Groups: [
      { Id: 1, Name: 'Actors' }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Brad Pitt',
    Groups: [
      { Id: 1, Name: 'Actors' },
      { Id: 2, Name: 'Aliens' }   <-- I don't want this group,
    ]                                 the link is soft deleted
  }
]
```

Since the link is soft deleted, I am expecting TypeORM to not include the Aliens group in the result set.